# Project with path ':react-native-google-sign-in' could not be found in project ':app' in React Native Android

Tags: react-native, react-native-firebase

I am getting project not found. I have a try to run but getting error could not be found in project ':app'.
Please help me.

`FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

Where:
Build file 'C:\Users\Vijay\lavisducagou\android\app\build.gradle' line: 159

What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.

Project with path ':react-native-google-sign-in' could not be found in project ':app'.

Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
BUILD FAILED`

versions

```
"dependencies": {
"@react-native-community/google-signin": "^4.0.3",
"react": "16.8.3",
"react-native": "0.59.5",
"react-native-firebase": "^5.3.1"}
```

Comment: i implementation this line work fine  `implementation project(":react-native-google-signin")` but  i right this line i got another error anu solution ? .`* What went wrong: Execution failed for task ':react-native-firebase:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'. > Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.`   any one have this solution ?help me

Comment: finally befire long trem i solved my issue

Comment: install `npm i jetifier` clear error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

remove

> implementation(project(":react-native-google-signin"))

from app/build.gradle

Comment: * What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.
> Project with path ':react-native-community_google-signin' could not be found in project ':app'.             bro look problem

Comment: just renove **implementation(project(":react-native-google-signin"))** don't add anything else

Comment: this line is right  `implementation project(":react-native-google-signin")` i right this line i got another error .`* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':react-native-firebase:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.`    any one have this solution ?

Comment: follow android installation guide [here](https://github.com/react-native-community/google-signin/blob/HEAD/docs/android-guide.md) and cross check every steps

Comment: No, I have tried all the implementations regardless of error is coming as you see

Comment: for _Execution failed for task ':react-native-firebase:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'_, run **npx jetify** in project root